# dynamic sql statement using codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, dynamic

I have a database set up with 2 tables: players and stats
for players the PRIMARY KEY is id.
for stats the PRIMARY KEY is id, but also has a foreign key of p_id.

I am trying to write s sql statement that will allow me to to return the stats for a certain player dynamically.

Here is what I have. If i change `$p_id = 1` or something of that nature then I get the results, however I wish to do this dynamically.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function get_stats_for_player($p_id) {
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('stats'); 
    $this->db->join('players', 'players.id = stats.p_id'); 
    $this->db->where('stats.p_id', $p_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: you want sql statement instead of this ? question is not properly defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your model function and query are correct.. how you are calling this function? make sure that you are passing $p_id parameter to the function

eg:-

```
$p_id = 1;
$players = $this->my_model->get_stats_for_player($p_id);
```